# Convert.ChangeType to DateTime returns different results on different machines

Tags: c#, .net

On my machine, running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Build 17134, the call to

```
Convert.ChangeType("1990-02-02T00:00:00.000+0300", typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

returns `02.02.1990 0:00:00`. Timezone setting is +3.

On our server, running Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Build 9600 though, the same call returns `01.02.1990 23:00:00`, which is the same moment in time but in UTC timezone. Timezone setting on the server is also +3, timed matches, date matches, everything I can think of matches. The only difference is that on my machine timezone is `(+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd`, and on the server it is `(UTC+03:00) Minsk`

Both returned values have `Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`

Could anybody please explain what is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505647/different-datetimeformat-for-the-same-culture-in-different-machines

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: @SeM, I know I could use that for `DateTime`, but this piece is the uniform integration adapter from external system, it is already unstable as it is, I can't make it anymore complex

Answer (score 0):

You should use an offset aware struct `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

```
var myDate = Convert.ChangeType("1990-02-02T00:00:00.000+0300", typeof(DateTimeOffset), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime utc = myDate.UtcDateTime;
```

This should give the same time.

The reason might be that at 1990 the timezones were different. I am not sure, but if you try to convert `DateTime.Now()` it should be identical.

Comment: Let's say that `typeof(DateTime)` comes from framework, I am given a type and I must return value of that type. I need to figure out why same code behaves differently

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to [Daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), which is present in `(UTC+03:00) Minsk` (Belarus), but not in `(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd` (Russia).

Thanks everybody for spent time.

Comment: So what was your solution? Post it here or move this answer to comments.

Comment: Solution is to switch server to `(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd`, which is where it actually is